# Restoring <textarea> scrollbar position on page reload

Tags: javascript, dom

Upon searching StackOverflow for restoring scrollbar position using JavaScript, I came across this suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812235/1101391

```
    document.getElementById("invoice_incomplete").scrollTop = 200px;
```

If I'm not mistaken, this code is somewhat related to what I really want to achieve. How can you actually save/remember/restore the position of the scrollbar on a `<textarea>` after reloading the page, and not just set your preferred scrollbar position?

Like when you type some paragraphs on the `<textarea>` and you reload the page, the scrollbar should be on its same position before reloading the page.

**Edit:**
Ended up using the `onunload` event, and an invisible `<input>` tag, as per mr. @ruakh's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the value in an invisible text-field that serves no other purpose:

```
<input style="display:none" id="scrollTop" />
```

you can use a `window.onunload` event *(hat-tip to katspaugh's comment)* to set

```
document.getElementById('scrollTop').value = textarea.scrollTop;
```

and a `window.onload` event to set

```
textarea.scrollTop = document.getElementById('scrollTop').value;
```

(The above assumes that `textarea` is a variable referring to the textarea).

When the browser reloads the page, if it restores the form contents, then it will restore the contents of the invisible text-field together with the contents of the textarea.

Comment: Sir, I mean the HTML's `<textarea>` tag.

Comment: @covanova: Yes, I know exactly what you mean. My code example assumes that `textarea` is a JavaScript variable referring to that `<textarea>`. (You haven't shown your own JavaScript code, or your own HTML code, so I had to give an example.)

Comment: @covanova His idea has some sense. It is in saving current position not in cookies or localStorage, but in input. I'm not sure, this is reliable storage, though.

Comment: @kirilloid : Yes, Sir! trying to write my code now using his suggestion.

Comment: @kirilloid: I've been using this approach for years to save data across reloads. (I use it to save `document.title`, but the idea is the same.) I've found it to be very reliable. I imagine it would, if anything, be even *more* reliable for covanova's problem, since covanova only needs the scrolling to happen if/when the rest of the form is successfully restored, so anything that made this approach fail would also render the failure irrelevant.

Comment: This one is very helpful: `<input style="display:none" id="scrollTop" />`. Thank you, Sir @ruakh

Comment: I think `<input type="hidden">` would be better than `<input style="display:none">`. [`type="hidden"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.hidden.html) more clearly shows the intent of saving data without displaying it.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: I see what you mean, but in practice, that doesn't always work quite as well; values of `type="hidden"` fields aren't restored in all cases that other form values are. For example, I've just tested in Firefox, and while it works across Forward/Back, it *doesn't* work when you close the tab and restore it via "Recently Closed Tabs".

Answer (score 1):

Save current scrollTop into cookies or localStorage on each scroll change (i.e. in `onscroll` event handler) and then restore it upon page load.

Comment: The problem with that approach is -- what happens if someone has the same page open in multiple tabs?

Comment: Well, then I know only one option for independent storage: URL's hash. Hmm, wait. Your idea will also work, event though it looks like dirty hack )

Comment: You can save the scroll position once, on `unload`.